# Javascript Code to be embedded in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS code to calculate the multiple of a number. I want to incorporate the same in my HTML file. So when I click the "Submit" button, it gives me the answer. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta author="Shruti Paliwal">
<title>Project Euler Solutions</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function multiples()
    {
        var i;
        sum=0;
        for(i=1;i<1000;i++)
        {
            if(i%3 === 0 || i%5 === 0)
                {
                    sum+=i;
                }

        }

    }
    document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>
<div id="header">
Project Euler
<sub>.net</sub>
</h3>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<p class="problem1" id="problem">
<b>
Multiples of 3 and 5
</b>
<div class="boundary" id="boundary">
<div class="content">
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
<br />
Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
<br />
<br />
<form>
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="button" onclick="sum()" value="Submit" />

</form>
</div>
</p>
</div>
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Need help to display the output of this code on my webpage. The logic to calculate multiples is working fine on a JS console. However, not getting how to incorporate the 2!!

Comment: You don't seem to have put much effort in this. ;P

Comment: line 37 is the culprit

Comment: You are using: 'document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;' Where is that ID on your html page? You also calling the function sum(). And call your working function on html multiples(), where is the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
<p class="problem1" id="problem">
    <b>
        Multiples of 3 and 5
    </b>
    <div class="boundary" id="boundary">
        <div class="content">
            If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
            <br />
            Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
            <br />
            <br />
            <form>
                <p>Enter number 1:</p><input type="text" id="txtNumber1">
                <br />
                <p>Enter number 2:</p><input type="text" id="txtNumber2">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="button" onclick="multiples()" value="Submit" />

                <input type="text" name="value" id="sum">


            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function multiples() {
        ////Jquery
        //var number1 = $("#txtNumber1").val();
        //var number2 = $("#txtNumber2").val();

        //Javascript
        var number1 = document.getElementById('txtNumber1').value;
        var number2 = document.getElementById('txtNumber2').value;

        if (number1.trim() == '' || number2.trim() == '')
        {
            alert('please enter number1 and number2');
            return false;
        }

        var i;
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (i % number1 === 0 || i % number2 === 0) {
                sum += i;
            }

        }
        document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The only problem in this solution is that there is no ID sum on the HTML side.

Comment: This function returns 233168 everytime for any number. How can I make this work with any random natural number??

Comment: You have to pass those two numbers as function parameter. function multiples(a,b)

Comment: If you could be a little more specific, I would be highly obliged.. I have added another box to display the result. Now, I want that the code should run for any given number.. be it 10, 20 or 1000

Comment: give me some time, will add the html

Comment: @SandipPatel But what is the need of a second number? Only one number needs to be entered, and the program will calculate the sum of multilples of 3 or 5 till that number. Eg: if I enter a number say 10, the result should be 23(3+5+6+9)

Comment: I made a few changes in your code as per the requirements and its working 100% accurately now!!!! @SandipPatel Thanks a lot for your kind help :)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 101

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
</script>
```

```html
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

OR

```js
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.innerHTML = myResult;

}
```

```html
<input id="box1" type="text" />
<input id="box2" type="text" />
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="submit" onclick="calculate()"/>
```